# Magento 2 graphQL Get Select attribute option labels in Products Query

Tags: magento2, products, graphql, select, labels

I want to get the attribute label value along with the id in the Products graphQL query.

like color { id: 12, label: black }, size{ id: 15, label: xl }

Currently, it returns the id only.

How can I extend the current query?

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

```
query($url: String!) {
  products(filter: { url_key: { eq: $url } }) {
    items {
      id
      sku
      name
      ... on ConfigurableProduct {
        configurable_options {
          id
          attribute_id_v2
          use_default
          attribute_code
          label
          position
          values {
            value_index
            label
            swatch_data {
              __typename
              value
            }
          }
          product_id
        }
        variants {
          attributes {
            label
            code
            value_index
          }
          product {
            id
            name
            sku
            stock_status
            short_description {
              html
            }
            description {
              html
            }
            image {
              url
              label
            }
            small_image {
              url
              label
            }
            media_gallery {
              url
              label
              ... on ProductVideo {
                video_content {
                  media_type
                  video_provider
                  video_url
                  video_title
                  video_description
                  video_metadata
                }
              }
            }
            price_range {
              minimum_price {
                regular_price {
                  value
                  currency
                }
                final_price {
                  value
                  currency
                }
                discount {
                  amount_off
                  percent_off
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    total_count
  }
}
```

Comment: this is for configurable products. I want this data in all simple products too

Comment: if the product is configurable then it's showing all its variants. Simple product does not have any variant

Comment: Simple products can also have various attributes with option/value combination.